# exposing custom types (classes) in a web service (WSE)

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wse

If I have custom types (classes) in my web service, do I have to mark with with special attributes so they are serialized properly?

i.e. [SomeAttribute] ?

**Update**
I am using WSE at the moment

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Data Contract serializer by default nothing is serialized - this is the opposite of the older XmlSerializer - which is the older asmx web service approach.

For WCF look at the DataContractAttribute for starters: [link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The obsolete WSE uses the XmlSerializer. It should serialize most public read/write properties of types that have a default constructor. For more details, look up XmlSerializer.

And convert from WSE to WCF as soon as possible, as WSE is obsolete.